# float problem in safari 

Tags: iphone, css, safari, stylesheet

i have this strange float probelm at www.firstavenuedesign.co.uk/demo/offers.aspx it seems to affect all sub pages in safari and iphone and firefox so it seems to be a common style problem with the content tag i have inlcuded it here

http://firstavenuedesign.co.uk/demo/offers.aspx

```
#content{
width:958px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:12px 0 150px 24px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
height :100%;
color:#333333;
}
```

can you wish kids have a look see what might be wrong

Comment: It seems like the float is simply too wide to fit into the space provided by the container?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to explain you problem.

test it:

```
#right_side {
clear: right;
float: left;
width: 626px;
}
```